# Build date difference in Excel Online in same cell using TODAY()

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Coming from the question on [`DATEDIF`](https://superuser.com/questions/1428628/datedif-in-excel-online-for-office-365/), I have found out the following.

I want to count days dynamically since some date in the past to today. Ideally, I would like to do so in the same cell. Software is Excel Online for Office 365.

What works:

- (1) Date difference between two static cells
- (2) Dynamic date difference between two cells, where one is static, and one has dynamic value TODAY().

What does not work:

- Dynamic date difference calculated as formula `TODAY()-CELL_X`.

Please find the screenshot below. Unfortunately, I do not have a normal desktop MS Excel software version to compare. In the LibreOffice calc this does not work neither.

While I can use (2) above as workaround, what's wrong with my assumption I could calculate date without one extra cell?

[image]

*Note*: `HEUTE` is the German word for `TODAY`.

Comment: Format F12 as number, not as date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I see it now - I need to set formatting to "integer", then in `F12` I get an integer number as desired. In `F10` and `F11` the software did it automatically.

Comment: You may use this also `=TEXT(TODAY()-E12,"##")` you get `14`.